# In F#, what do you call a type defined as a function signature

Tags: f#

In F#, is there a special name for a type defined in the following manner:

```
type Foo = int -> string
```

I ask because such a type seems to have special significance. It is quite abstract compared to other types and seems to only be usable as a sort of function interface. It is not discussed much in F# literature, but it is used quite a bit in the source of many F# OSS projects.

Is it a special sort of type that has some broader significance in functional programming? Does it have other applications other than functioning as a sort of interface for functions? Why is it something that doesn't really make sense to instantiate, even though you can kind of do that by defining a function with a matching type signature? Or is it really just as simple as saying that it is an alias for a function definition which can then be used as a short form in other type signatures/definitions and that accounts for all it's properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name used in the F# documentation for this kind of definition is [type abbreviation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/type-abbreviations-%5Bfsharp%5D) and I think many people often refer to it as *type alias*.

The definition defines an alias or a shorter name for a longer type. It says that whenever you type `Foo`, the compiler will see it as `int -> string`.

- Type abbreviations do not define a *new* type, which means that `Foo` and `int -> string` are equivalent (a value of one type is also a value of the other type). The important points are:
- Type inference will generally infer the original type, so when you write a function that matches the type, compiler will infer it as `int -> string` unless you give an explicit type annotation
- When compiled, the abbreviations are erased (because .NET does not have such concept) and so the compiled code will see `int -> string`.

Abbreviations are useful just for readability reasons - it lets you use more descriptive name for a type. However, they do not have many other implications.

Comment: I would add that, even though the abbreviations are erased _as far as CLR is concerned_, they would still be visible to other F# code that references the compiled library.